# Writing a parser with M, consume while not rule

Tags: oslo, mgrammar

I'm writing a HTML parser for my own amusement and I wanted to try out M.

I base this work on the HTML 4.01 standard and in there it says

> Although the STYLE and SCRIPT elements
>   use CDATA for their data model, for
>   these elements, CDATA must be handled
>   differently by user agents. Markup and
>   entities must be treated as raw text
>   and passed to the application as is.
>   The first occurrence of the character
>   sequence "</" (end-tag open delimiter)
>   is treated as terminating the end of
>   the element's content. In valid
>   documents, this would be the end tag
>   for the element.

I think about it for a while and really what I wanna do is something like this

```
syntax Main 
    = "<script>" Script "</script>"
    ;
token Script
    = TakeWhileNot("</") // this is not valid M grammar
    ;
```

I find my self finding that I want to perform some kind of tokenization rule that matches until I reach an open angle bracket < followed by a forward slash /.

If the escape sequence was a single character this would not be a problem because then I could have written this.

```
token Script
    = ScriptEscape+
    ;
token ScriptEscape
    = !"<"
    ;
```

And that would work, not sure if I'm going about this the right way but the problem is sort of related to that I have a language embedded in another but I don't care about the script language in this case so I simply want to skip a head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this neat trick, which wasn't entirely obvious...

```
syntax Main 
    = "<script>" Script* "</script>"
    ;
token Script
    = !('<')
    | '<' !('/')
    ;
```

Now that's valid MGrammar, which translates into:

- Do NOT take '<' OR take '<' NOT followed by '/'

Which would consume anything until a </ token is encountered without consuming it.